# In Magento 2 - How to remove a column in customer_entity table?

Tags: magento2, customer

In Magento 2, How to remove a column in `customer_entity` table?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your setup script, we can use `dropColumn`:

```
 $setup->getConnection()->dropColumn($setup->getTable('your_table'), 'your_column');
```

Comment: doing with `UpgradeSchema.php ` is a better and cleaner solution

Answer (score 7):

You can try this simple **dropColumn()** function in your **installer script**.

```
$this->startSetup();

//example: 
$this->getConnection()->dropColumn($this->getTable('your_table_definition'), 'your column name', $schemaName = null)

$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: thank your answer!

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution, maybe good for referring for other.
I created `Tohq\Customer\Setup\UpgradeSchema.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Tohq\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {            
        // Version of module in setup table is less then the give value.
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.1.4', '<')) {

            // get table customer_entity
            $eavTable = $setup->getTable('customer_entity');

            // Check if the table already exists
            if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($eavTable) == true) {
                $connection = $setup->getConnection();

                // del_flg = column name which you want to delete
                $connection->dropColumn($eavTable, 'del_flg');
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Path: Magento22/app/code/Aks/Training/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Aks_Training" setup_version="1.0.2"/>
</config>
```

Create UpgradeSchema.php file under Setup folder in your module.

**Path: Magento22/app/code/Aks/Training/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php**

```
<?php
    namespace Aks\Training\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

    /**
     * Upgrade the Sales_Order Table to remove extra field
     */
    class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
    {

        public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
                $setup->getConnection()->dropColumn($setup->getTable('sales_order'), 'gst');
            }
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

I hope It's work for ever